# Eclipse CDT, build settings - Hello World

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Okay, I'm pretty new to CDT, making the transition from simple text editors, and I'm struggling to understand how to tweak the settings correctly to get a project built. Specifically what I'm trying to do right now is to run a simple Hello World using ClanLib external libraries. Now normally I would run this command (and have done so successfully):

```
g++ -o mygame mygame.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs clanCore-2.3 clanDisplay-2.3 clanGL-2.3 clanGL1-2.3 clanApp-2.3` -lpthread
```

What I would like help on, is how to essentially translate this command to Ecplise. I've been trying out different options, and it's just not working for me, and I haven't found any comprehensive tutorial for this either. More specifically I would like help on how to get the

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs clanCore-2.3 clanDisplay-2.3 clanGL-2.3 clanGL1-2.3 clanApp-2.3`
```

part into Eclipse, as I assume the -lpthread gets added to the Libraries part of the GCC C++ Linker. I would really love to get some help, as it's driving me a little nuts, trying to get it to work (it's a little frustrating trying to set something up like this, when I would love nothing more than to actually get started on my project).

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for eclipse that can handle this for you:
http://code.google.com/p/pkg-config-support-for-eclipse-cdt/

flindt

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a make and a makefile targets just to get up and going?  Otherwise I'm thinking you need to modify the C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols and C/C++ General->Discovery Options sections of the project properties.